# Google Play Market hangs

Tags: google-play-store

I've just updated to Android 4.3, OTA.
Now when I try to start Google Play, it hangs.
Here is a part of log:

```
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.PlayTabContainer.onPageScrolled(PlayTabContainer.java:120)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.activities.TabbedBrowseFragment.onPageScrolled(TabbedBrowseFragment.java:462)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.activities.TabbedBrowseFragment.rebindViews(TabbedBrowseFragment.java:345)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.fragments.PageFragment.onDataChanged(PageFragment.java:256)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.activities.TabbedBrowseFragment.onDataChanged(TabbedBrowseFragment.java:296)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeModel.notifyDataSetChanged(DfeModel.java:100)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.api.model.PaginatedList.onResponse(PaginatedList.java:370)
07-31 09:27:47.683: E/AndroidRuntime(20321):    at com.google.android.finsky.api.DfeRequest.deliverResponse(DfeRequest.java:488)
```

I am totally locked! What can I do to enter Google Play?!

Comment: Have you tried to wipe the cache or data for the play app?

Comment: I agree with @ott, this is a common problem when upgrading the Android OS, clearing the cache should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache doesn't work then another option would be to uninstall updates to the Play app. In a lot of cases this seems to do the trick.